# OpenCV can't be found but can be imported

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I've installed opencv from source using a virtualenv, however I faced some errors and needed to reinstall it. I tried removing all the files with `sudo find / -name "opencv" -exec rm {} \;` and checked if the package was removed with `pkg-config --modversion opencv`, and it said it could not be found, but when I open the terminal with `python3` and enter `import cv2` then `print(cv2.__version__)`, the terminal returns `4.0.0`. How can I completely remove opencv? I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I hadn't uninstalled in the build folder, problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Run this command from your installed environment.

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
```

and if you are using Python3 than

```
pip3 uninstall opencv-python
```

Comment: I entered `python3 -c "import cv2 as _; print(_.__file__)"` in terminal and got 
`/home/bruno_domingues/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` as output

Comment: I tried, on pip it uninstalled but on pip3 it says it's not installed..
I entered `python3 -c "import cv2 as _; print(_.__file__)"` in terminal and got 
`/home/bruno_domingues/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` as output, so I tried deleting the folder. I can import cv2 but when I try printing the version it says `cv2 has no attribute __version__`, so not sure if it worked.

Comment: This may happen because of 2 resoans:
1. You installed with pip and uninstalled in pip3 and vice versa
2. If you have installed Anaconda then it points to two different path of python. So uninstall after activating the environment. To activate type ```source activate env_name ```. If you have not created any environment than write env_name as ```base``` so write ```source activate base```