# Uninstall openCV on python 2 and python 3

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, installation

OS: Ubuntu 18.04-LTS bionic

i downloaded openCV using the command
`sudo apt-get install python-opencv` from the link

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html

This installs openCV 4.2 onto both my python 2.7 & python 3.6.9.
I wanted to remove openCV and i used this command in terminal 
`sudo apt-get --purge autoremove python-opencv`
When i call the version in terminal

```
    python
 import cv2
 cv2.__version__
```

only python2.7 openCV is removed but not python3.6.9.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple python versions you can run cmd commands like this:

`py -3.X -m pip uninstall opencv-python`

So use this to try uninstalling opencv for every python version you have installed.

Comment: i had the same problem as this person https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54826979/opencv-cant-be-found-but-can-be-imported but i could not uninstall the opencv after trying both your method and the link, only cv2.so file appears

Comment: Yes, umm I made a mistake :/ I coppied from your question but the actual package is `opencv-python` **NOT** `python-opencv`